# npm shows error when to install `angular-in-memory-web-api`

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular-in-memory-web-api

I am new to Angular. I was going through [Angular 7 official documents](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) and tried to install `angular-in-memory-web-api` using npm. But it shows the following error.

#### Command:

`npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save`

#### Error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ angular-in-memory-web-api@0.8.0
updated 1 package and audited 42612 packages in 12.78s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I tried to fix the error using `npm audit fix` but it doesn't help. Shows the following error.

#### Command:

`npm audit fix`

#### Error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 9.474s
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 42612 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try different version of it?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17671

Comment: It not error. Package have optional dependency for Mac OS. Because you install package to Windows PC, you don't need this package and NPM pass it.

Comment: I am using npm version 6.7.0. The latest version is 6.9.0. Do you think its a problem with version? I tried to upgrade using the command `npm install -g npm@latest` but this also shows this error:  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/TjW5D7tfnp/